# javascript preventing special characters in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to restrict the usage of the following special characters `<>{}` in a textarea. I am making use of this Alphanumeric Plugin for jQuery (https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum).

My script is as follows:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#ta_0', function(e){
    blacklisted_characters = $('#ta_0').alphanum({ disallow : '<>{}' }); // Specify characters to disallow
    if (blacklisted_characters) {
        if (!!$.prototype.fancybox)
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    type: 'inline',
                    autoScale: true,
                    minHeight: 30,
                    content: '<p class="fancybox-error">' + 'Désolé, l\'utilisation de ce caractère n\'est pas autorisée.' + '</p>'
                }],
                {
                    padding: 0
                });
        else
            alert('Désolé, l\'utilisation de ce caractère n\'est pas autorisée.');
    };

});
```

The pop up should appear in case those special characters has been written in the textarea. But i think there is an error in my code, because its preventing me from adding texts in the textarea and poping up the error message everytime.

The plugin works with this only:

```
$('#ta_0').alphanum({ 
    disallow           : '<>{}' 
});
```

It is the if condition that i am doing wrong. The id of my textarea is `$ta_0`.I just need to make an if condition so identify if the following characters are written in the textarea `<>{}`. If those characters are written in the textarea, it should fire up the error popup.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: the plug in do the testing? because I can't see where are you comparing `e.which` to your "blacklisted_characters" but then again, I'm not familiarized with the plugin...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL i have edited my post to answer you.

Comment: The documentation say the plugin have this black list: `var blacklist = '!@#$%^&*()+=[]\\\';,/{}|":<>?~`.- _';` why are you disallowing `'<>{}'` again? and thank you for the edit.

Comment: Try: `$('#ta_0').alphanum({ allow :  '!@#$%^&*()+=[]\\\';,/|":?~`.- _' });` it will leave in the blacklist only: '<>{}'.

Comment: thank you @DIEGOCARRASCAL i did that but still the script doesnt seem to be working properly because 'backlisted_characters' is always true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function: `$('#ta_0').alphanum({ disallow : '<>{}' });` does not return the input character as a value, it returns an array of inputs that have been selected using the jQuery selector, in this case `#ta_0`. Since those inputs exist on your page, it will always return true, which causes the popup to continue to run.

You'll have to restructure your code in a few ways.

1. Move `$('#ta_0').alphanum({ disallow : '<>{}' });` outside the keyup function
2. Find the keycodes for your blacklisted inputs (<>{})
3. Check the **event** (in this case `e`) inside your keyup function against those keycodes to decide whether to display the fancybox.

**To clarify step 3:** It looks like it would be difficult to do this with `keyup`, because the characters all require the *Shift* key as a modifier. But using `keypress`, you get a unique code for *Shift+key*.

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#ta_0", function(event) {
  blacklisted_characters = [
    123, // {
    125, // }
    60, // <
    62 // >
  ];
  if (blacklisted_characters.indexOf(event.which) >= 0) {
    alert("Désolé, l\'utilisation de ce caractère n\'est pas autorisée.");
  }
});
```

I tried to make a fiddle combining this with the alphanum plugin, but there seemed to be a problem loading github user content. [But here you can see an example of the code above](https://jsfiddle.net/153cm74q/)

Comment: what did you mean by this:
2. Find the keycodes for your blacklisted inputs (<>{})
Can you explain please?

Comment: anyone who can help please?

Comment: I believe the plugin do that for you, [Blacklist](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum#blacklist)

Comment: @user786 - A key event in JavaScript returns a keycode, which is an integer based on which key was pressed. You can find out which number is assigned to which key here: http://keycode.info/

Comment: @Shaun can you tell me how to do this and give code samples

3. Check the event (in this case e) inside your keyup function against those keycodes to decide whether to display the fancybox.

Comment: @user786 I added a code example for step 3. I'm not sure if there is some benefit to `keyup` over `keypress`, but it looks like `keypress` would be better for this case.

Comment: @Shaun, thank you. Your piece of codes works perfectly. But only issue now is, when {}<> is pressed, the alert message appears, but those characters still shows in the textarea. Meaning i would like that if those characters are inserted in textarea, the alert message appears but the characters doesnt shows in the textarea. Thank you

Comment: Are you still using the `alphanum` library? In addition to the code shown in step 3, you will need to add the line: `$('#ta_0').alphanum({ disallow : '<>{}' });`. As I mentioned in step 1, it should be outside of the `keypress` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's not elegant, and you have to tweek it a little to make it better, but it does what I believe you need:

```
$("#myText").on("keyup",function(event){
    //console.log(event.which);
    if(event.which == 219 || event.which == 221 || event.which == 188 || event.which == 190)
        {
            $("#myText").val($("#myText").val().replace(/<|>|{|}/gi,""));
        }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i tried your codes like this

$("#ta_0").on("keyup",function(event){
    //console.log(event.which);
    if(event.which == 219 || event.which == 221 || event.which == 188 || event.which == 190)
        {
            $("#ta_0").val($("#ta_0").val().replace(/<|>|{|}/gi,""));
        }
});

But it didnt work. Maybe i did soemthing wrong!

Comment: are you creating dynamically the input element? if you do you must refer to it like 
`$(document).on("keyup","#myText",function(event){if(event.which == 219 || event.which == 221 || event.which == 188 ||event.which == 190){$("#myText").val($("#myText").val().replace(/<|>|{|}/gi,""));}});` and control the propagation of the event, if any...